# jquery show not defaulting to hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this pretty simple jquery example:  http://jsfiddle.net/clifgray/NTd95/1/ and in that jsfiddle it works exactly like I want it to.  When I implement it on a webpage with very little difference in the code, except for some preexisting content, the jquery section defaults to showing the content in the hidden div.  It still works when I click hide and from there I can show and hide alright but I want it to be hidden when I start the webpage.

Is there any reason that you can think of for this happening?

Comment: Is it possible to see the preexisting content?

Comment: _"very little difference"_ - Obviously these differences matter, so you need to show more code. Do you have the same styles defined on your webpage as in the fiddle?

Comment: If the CSS is setting the relevant `div` to `display: none`, then it should not be shown. If it is, then there is either something else that is showing it, or there is styling coming from somewhere else that has a higher specificity and is therefore overwriting yours.

Comment: check your other css codes or files there might be another definition for `div`. you do it by right click-Inspect element...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having, is you are using a blanket css rule for **all** div's instead of being specific to the divs you are trying to target. My guess is that somewhere on your page you have change the display away from `none`

Add this before your javascript:

```
$("#box1, #box2").hide();
```

...or change your css rule to this:

```
div#box1, div#box2 { background:#def3ca; margin:3px; width:80px; display:none; float:left; text-align:center; }
```

...or add this inline with your html:

```
<div id="box1" style="display:none">
```

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. I used the first solution and it was a blanket CSS rule that I just couldn't find at first because a friend wrote the CSS.